# Can NSOpenPanel be configured to not close after OK/Cancel buttons are clicked?

Tags: cocoa, nsopenpanel

I would like to animate the close operation instead. However, I have not had any luck figuring out how to keep the NSOpenPanel from disappearing offscreen as soon as the OK or Cancel buttons are clicked.

Comment: You would probably have to subclass it and override the appropriate method(s). It may be sufficient to override `-orderWindow:relativeTo:` although you may need `-close`, too. This may be fragile. What sort of animation are you trying to do? How does the rest of the UI work (w.r.t. your comment on Peter's answer)?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to animate the close operation instead.

One way would be to present your Open panel as a sheet, in which case Cocoa will animate both its appearance and its disappearance for you. Nine times out of ten, this is the correct way to present your Open (or Save) panel anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the option to present it as a sheet, but the sheet animation does not match well with the rest of the UI. This is the 1 out of 10 case.